# Is it pertinent to display any | all buttons when favorite tag is used

Tags: discussion, new-nav

In the [new-nav](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav), we can select in <kbd>Need answer</kbd> the questions that are about our favorite tag.

Then, with this switch <kbd>Any | All</kbd>:

[image]

We can select if the displayed questions must contains one or *all* of our favorite tags.

This makes no sense for users with more than 5 favorite tags... And it bothers me (more than it should) since it's useless (to me).

Am I the only one feeling this? Is there a way to display it under certain conditions?

Comment: If all else fails you can install [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/help/stylish) and hide it yourself.